# Error:Could not set the value of environment variable 'LANGUAGE': could not convert string to current locale

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using android studio to create an android project. I only created an empty activity project, and I edited nothing.

However, I always get the below gradle error:

`Gradle 'mytest' project refresh failed
Error:Could not set the value of environment variable 'LANGUAGE': could not convert string to current locale`

I don't know where the environment variable `LANGUAGE` is.
I started my android studio with the command `sudo ./studio.sh`. I am confused why I could not set it.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: I just encountered this error myself in a totally different situation. I don't know how to solve it, yet, but if you could add the output of `echo $LANGUAGE`, that will tell us what the value of `LANGUAGE` is so we can get an idea what may be wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same error message with a different environment variable, `pull_title`, which was being set in my case by a DevOps tool that I was using. I don't know exactly why, but the value it had disagreed with gradle.

You check your environment variable with `echo $LANGUAGE` at your terminal. If the value is empty, check the contents of `studio.sh` to see if they are setting `LANGUAGE` with a call like `export LANGUAGE=somevalue` or `LANGUAGE=somevalue; export LANGUAGE`. If it isn't empty and it isn't set in `studio.sh`, try changing it with `export LANGUAGE=` to see if it works. If it does, add that command to your `studio.sh` file so that variable is always unset when you execute Android Studio without affecting your shell or other programs.